# Where does the Piña colada song play in the Guardians of the Galaxy movie?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1, guardians-of-the-galaxy

In an interview with Chris Pratt he said that now hates the Piña colada song because of the movie. I know the song is on the soundtrack, but where is it in the movie?

Comment: Are you sure it was the piña colada song he hates? I thought it was "Come and get your love"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found it. It's kinda in the middle, right after Quill goes back for his cassette.

For a little more detail:

> It is at the end of the escape from Kiln, When he goes back to get his cassette, and then flies back to the Milano.

Comment: why is this in a spoiler tag?

Comment: @NathanK.Campbell Because it's a spoiler for the movie. Is there a statute of limitations on this site, that has expired?

Comment: @McKay "Your answer must make sense without spoiler-protected paragraphs.
If the spoiler is the whole point of your answer, don't spoiler protect it." - SE Meta post: [Policy for spoilers on fiction or literature sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114923/162827)

Comment: @galacticninja I don't think that answer qualifies as a policy, but I've given a non-spoiler answer too. Does that meet your satisfaction?

Comment: @galacticninja That meta-answer is prefaced with the statement that that is not network policy, and is only that person's personal rule. The other answers there likewise state that there is no network-wide policy regarding spoilers. However, you can put in your two cents on our [meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/968/what-is-the-policy-for-spoilers) if you want to help build a local consensus.

Comment: @Xantec It's not policy, spoiler protection is optional. It's meant to be guidance on how to write answers with potential spoilers. The answers in that meta post you link say the same. What I'm saying is that if almost your *entire* answer is hidden in spoiler markdown, then you probably want to ease up a bit on the spoiler markdown. The answer must make sense without the spoiler-protected text.  `@McKay Your current edit is much better.

Comment: @galacticninja I understand now that you weren't meaning to quote policy, but your original text included the phrase "Your answer must", which sounds pretty authoritative.

Comment: @McKay It's a quote, an excerpt, of a (highly upvoted) meta answer post. Meta discussion answer posts, like the one I linked to above, are *suggesting* policy, which explains why it sounds authoritative. Policy or not, my point is it does not look good for almost an *entire* answer to be hidden in spoiler markdown (like yours was *before* my comment). `@Xantec's linked meta post above says the same: "Put as little text as possible into the spoiler tag…"